# Is it possible to bind to a control's property from a datatemplate?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, datatemplate, listpicker

Ok, sounds odd, and there's likely a better way, but I haven't seen it yet.

What I'm trying to do is restyle a ListPicker under Windows Phone 7.

What I need is to

1. get rid of the header (that's easy, just define a null ListPicker.HeaderTemplate).
2. Force the picker to always go to full mode when clicked (again, easy, just set the ItemCountThreshold to 1).
3. Restyle the itemtemplate used when in FullMode (again, easy, just define a FullModeItemTemplate)
4. Incorporate the ListPicker's "HEADER" property value into the ItemTemplate (since only one item will ever show, i need the header text "embedded" within the one item).

It's that number 4 that I can't seem to get.

I've defined a listpicker like so (i'm directly defining the templates inline instead of in resources for now, just to keep things simple).

```
        <phonekit:ListPicker Header="Header Text" x:Name="ListOfSounds" 
                             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=DepartureChime, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource EnumDescriptionToStringConverter}}"  
                             ItemCountThreshold="1">
            <phonekit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="Transparent">
                         <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Header}" />
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                         <TextBlock Text=">" />
                     </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phonekit:ListPicker.ItemTemplate>
```

Ignoring all the obvious formatting bits for now, the problem I'm having is that I can't use {TemplateBinding Header} from within a datatemplate. I've used it from a ControlTemplate no problem.

The result of this ItemTemplate should be an item displayed such as

```
 {TextOfHeader}{Content of selected Item}>
```

I'm just not sure how to go about getting at a property of the templated control (the listpicker in this case).

Any ideas?

Comment: WP7 uses silverlight, not WPF

Comment: True enough. When you're starting out, they both look very similar though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take advantages of [RelativeSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.relativesource.aspx):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type phonekit:ListPicker}}}" />
```

Comment: `RelativeSource` is only available if you are targetting the Mango/7.1 SDK as 7.0 uses Silverlight 3.

Comment: I'd found relativesource, but I've never been able to get it to work.

Comment: Ugh.... Just recently updated to Mango, and I show my reference to Microsoft.Phone as being to a SL4.0 folder. But when I try that syntax, I get "The property 'AncestorType' was not fount in type "RelativeSource". When I look up the relativesource type, though it shows to be from System.Windows which is coming from an SL4.0 folder as well. Specifically C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\Profile\WindowsPhone71\System.Windows.dll

Comment: I've got to have a reference out of whack, just not sure which one.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it might not be possible with SL4 either, I found several posts on MSDN indicating that AncestorType is only supported in SL5 (ugh), but Mango is SL4.0

Comment: I'm going to close this one out and accept this answer. It's right, just not availalable on WP7 (at least not yet)